# iOS - HTML source is different than when inspecting element in Chrome on desktop

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I am trying to get the html of a website to put in my iOS app. When I log the html from an NSData variable through an NSURLConnection, the html is different if I then went to the website on my desktop and clicked inspect element on the element that I am trying to find in the iOS html. Why would it be different? Is it because I clicked specifically on that element? It looks the same on iOS and the desktop because I have it loaded into a UIWebView.

**Update:** I have been told that in Chrome it is the rendered source code. How can I get the rendered source code in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome's Developer Console, it's showing rendered source codes (after AJAX and extension's modifications). Code mistakes (such as unclosed tags) will be fixed too.

It's NOT your original source code.

Comment: How could I get what the chrome console shows on iOS?

Comment: I know that the chrome console won't show, but do you mean I can't get the rendered html? I realized the info is loaded after the page has loaded. How can I get that HTML? When I use a webview and use JavaScript to get inner or outer html all it returns is <html><head><\head><body><\body><\html>.